# Compare two .CSV files and output the duplicate names

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I'm new to Powershell, and the title pretty much points out what I'm trying to do. I have here two .CSV files that includes the usernames of a group and the other an OU. I need to compare the userlist of the group and the OU then proceed with deleting the duplicates from the group in AD.

I've been googling around, and have found a few leads, but me being a new Powersheller I have not been able to combine what I've found into a working command that does what I want it to.

Here is the format of the .CSV files that I want to be compared. Samaccountname (the header) should not be compared.

```
"samaccountname"
"tb2"
"tb3"
"tb4"
```

Comment: See Compare-Object in your doc. And please, show your existing script ...

Comment: I have looked at Compare-Object. I have this script that shows me which usernames are in either both the group and OU, which is only in the group, and which is the only in the OU. Basically, I want it only to show which ones are in both, and then export it to a new file from where I can specify to Powershell which users to delete. Here's the script: http://pastebin.com/dFGMgDjH

Comment: Use "-includeequal" and filter on the SideIndicator to only keep matching values.

Comment: I tried, but can't make it work, also Googled a bit on the matching thing. As mentioned I'm new to Powershell, I hoped you could help me a bit with the code, or atleast just lead me a bit on the way,

Comment: Hi, I've been playing around, and I made it work. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/MpPbxvHC - thanks for your time!

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Group = import-csv -path C:\Output\Test.csv
$OU = import-csv -path C:\Output\DomainUsers.csv
Compare-Object $Group $OU -property samaccountname -IncludeEqual | where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | Export-csv C:\Output\Difference.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

is the code I was looking for.

Comment: Don't post link to code. This might prevent users to see your solutions in the future.