# Compare two CSV file and append the missing entries from 2nd to 1st

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, append

I am trying to compare 2 csv files using 'user Id' column which is common in both the files and want to append  the missing entries in csv 1 from csv 2 using power shell

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2011/02/08/compare-two-different-csv-files-using-powershell/ 

Try this to compare first

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601492/powershell-compare-two-csv-files-and-output-the-duplicate-names

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Answer (score 0):

If the first CSV file has missing rows, and they need to be copied in from the second CSV file directly:

```
ipcsv 2.csv |? 'User Id' -notin (ipcsv 1.csv).'User Id' | epcsv 1.csv -Append
```

If you're also saying that User IDs are unique in your files, you could instead take the unique rows out of the set of both CSVs into the first CSV:

```
(ipcsv 1.csv, 2.csv) | sort -Unique 'User Id' | epcsv 1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Alternatively, if you're saying that the files have the same User Ids but don't have the same other columns, and the entries in the first CSV are present but have some empty columns, then:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv d:\file1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv d:\file2.csv

foreach ($csv1item in $csv1)
{
    $csv2item = $csv2.Where{$_.'User Id' -eq $csv1item.'User Id'}

    $item1Properties = $csv1item | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $item2Properties = $csv2item | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $sharedProperties = $item1Properties.where{$_ -in $item2Properties}

    $sharedProperties | ForEach-Object {

        $value = $csv1item."$_"
        if ($value -eq '') {
            $csv1item."$_" = $csv2item."$_"
        }
    }
}

$csv1 | Export-Csv D:\file1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Alternatively again, if you're saying the two files have different columns which overlap at 'User Id' and also the entries are missing from the first CSV entirely, rather than being present with missing columns, then this will add them from the second CSV, taking only the properties which overlap between them (hopefully):

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv d:\file1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv d:\file2.csv

$item1Properties = ($csv1[0] | gm -M NoteProperty).Name

$newCsv1Items = foreach($csv2item in $csv2.Where{$csv1.'User Id' -notcontains $_.'User ID'}) {

    $newcsv1Item = @{}
    $item1Properties.ForEach{$newcsv1Item."$_" = $csv2item."$_"}
    [PSCustomObject]$newcsv1Item

}

$newCsv1Items | Export-Csv -Append D:\file1.csv
```